# How to implement theme shortcodes in text outside of pages?

Tags: shortcode

I am working on a project where the admin can enter text that will be presented in a custom template. Once the text is written it is saved to the dB then pulled out and presented when needed.

The problem is that the theme we are using uses shortcodes for some of the design elements. So when the shortcodes are used in this text, and the text is 'echoed' back, the shortcodes are ignored.

Is there someway to pre-process the text so WP will insert the shortcodes?

These shortcodes are not mine, they are from the theme, so the text needs to recognize and activate these shortcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the text through [`do_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
echo do_shortcode( $your_text_with_shortcodes );
```

or you can apply `the_content` filters to the text, which does the same thing as above along with some additional formatting goodies, like auto paragraphs and texturize:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $your_text_with_shortcodes);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the 'do_shortcode' but I thought that was for individual shortcodes.